# Exchange server POP connector options

Tags: exchange-2007

I've been using [this](http://www.quantumsoftware.com.au/ProductsServices/ExchangeConnector.aspx) software for a while now, and it's been great. Recently I'm finding that users mail isn't being downloaded to their Exchange mailbox, and they only way to get it is to login to the host email server.

The main issue is that the company is located in Australia, so support takes quite a while to get back to me. Are there any other products out there that you have used that work well, with stateside support?

EDIT: I should mention that this is Exchange 2007, on a 64bit platform.

EDIT2: I figured out the issue i had today, which was a corrupt item in the mailbox, both Popcon and Popbeamer were tested, to no avail. I did fool around with both apps, and i did like the fact that Popcon would give me real-time status of the current operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out it wasn't an issue with the actual software, but a corrupt message on the POP server.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of POP3 connectors I have used, primarily with SBS 2003, but I have also used them with Exchange 2007 with no issue:

- [PopCon](http://www.christensen-software.com/popcon.htm)
- [PopBeamer](http://www.dataenter.com/products/popbeamer.htm)

Both have worked great pulling down multiple pop mailboxes and catchall accounts and distributing to Exchange recipients.

Answer (score 1):

**XWall** (for anti-spam) and **PopBeamer** are both amazing products that I have used on over 50 installs of 5-100 users with no problems.  XWall/PopBeamer support is amazing, and reply promptly via email with technical solutions, rather than "did you try rebooting" style solutions.